# Placing JSON values from a json response, to HTML elements

Tags: jquery, html, json, parsing

Every 2 seconds, I send out a POST that returns:

```
[{"a":false,"i":"58","b":"sergio","p":"0,22","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"59","b":"sergio","p":"0,23","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"60","b":"sergio","p":"0,14","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"61","b":"sergio","p":"0,07","t":15}]
```

I have a Javascript function that captures this information and I'd like it to also parse the JSON and place the values into their appropriate elements.

```
function updateauctions(response) {
    //Parse JSON and place into HTML elements.

    //For debug purposes.
    alert(response);
}
```

I'm using jQuery and I'd like to know how to fetch JSON values, and place them into HTML elements.

An example of a div `.auctionbox`:

```
<div id="60" class="auctionbox gold">
    //Other things here.
</div>
```

For example, I have `n` amount of divs with class `.auctionbox` and each one of those divs also has an ID of `#i`. So each JSON object corresponds to a single `.auctionbox`. How would I place the `p` value of the JSON into the appropriate `#i`, `.auctionbox`?

With this simple example, I can start working on other requirements, I just need a little nudge. :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/mA4Ye/4/

Solution with using the template if you need to perform some specific html + css

html

```
<div id="data">
    <div class="template auctionbox"></div>
</div>
```

js

```
var json = '[{"a":false,"i":"58","b":"sergio","p":"0,22","t":15},' +
    '{"a":false,"i":"59","b":"sergio","p":"0,23","t":15},' +
    '{"a":false,"i":"60","b":"sergio","p":"0,14","t":15},' +
    '{"a":false,"i":"61","b":"sergio","p":"0,07","t":15}]';

var data = $.parseJSON(json);
var $template = $('.template');

$(data).each(function() {
    var $element = $template.clone().removeClass('template').appendTo('#data');
    $element.attr('id', this.i);
    $element.html(this.p);
});
```

Comment: Your answer is very well written and tech agnostic. I love it!

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.getJSON('your-json-url', function(json) {
        $(json).each(function() {
            $('#'+this.i).html(this.p);
        });
    });
}, 2000);
```

hope this helps

Comment: And how would I invoke that getJSON every 2 seconds? Currently I have a generated hidden link that's .Click()'d every 2 seconds using a javascript timer.

Comment: if you use var my_interval = setInterval ... you can also use clearInterval(my_interval) to stop the whole process

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(data); // data is the returned JSON string
for( var i in obj){
    $('.auctionbox'+i).html( obj[i].a );
}
```

That would add the contents of `obj.a` into a div with the class `.auctionbox0`, `auctionbox1`, etc.

Also, I'm not sure you an use numbers as IDs on HTML elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
var response = [{"a":false,"i":"58","b":"sergio","p":"0,22","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"59","b":"sergio","p":"0,23","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"60","b":"sergio","p":"0,14","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"61","b":"sergio","p":"0,07","t":15}];

function updateauctions(response) {
    for (i=0; i<response.length; i++){
    //if the ids are unique just leave the class alone and select the div with the id
    var id = 'div#'+response[i].i;

    $(id).html(response[i].p);
    //For debug purposes.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming the json response is already parsed to a js object (using `dataType: "json"` with `$.ajax()` or setting the optional 4th parameter to `"json"` with `$.get()` or `$.post()`), you can loop through the json array using `$.each()`, then navigate to each `div` to set it's value.

```
$.each(response,function(i,item) {
  $("#id-" + item.i).html(item.p);
});
```

Note: id's cannot start with a number, they must start with an alpha character. because of this, i assumed you would add id- to the id's.

Edit: here's how i would suggest doing it every 2 seconds:

```
var timer;
(function ajaxInterval(){
  $.getJSON(url,data,function(){
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      ajaxInterval();
    },2000);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this inside your function:

```
$.each(response, function(key, item) {
    $('#' + item.i).text(item.p);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I second Samich's answer and say use a templating engine that specializes in converting json to html like [json2html](http://www.json2html.com)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://json2html.com/js/jquery.json2html-2.3-min.js"></script>

<div id='list'></div>

<script>

var json =
[{"a":false,"i":"58","b":"sergio","p":"0,22","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"59","b":"sergio","p":"0,23","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"60","b":"sergio","p":"0,14","t":15},
{"a":false,"i":"61","b":"sergio","p":"0,07","t":15}];

//Transform used to create the div
var transform = 
    {tag:'div',id:'.i',class:'actionbox gold',children:[
        {tag:'span',html:'.b'},
        {tag:'span',html:' + other stuff'}
    ]};

//Render the json into a list of divs
$('#list').json2html(json, transform);
</script>
```